# Correct usage of "cover a lot of ground"?

Tags: idioms

I want to describe the topics along with the idiom like:

> "covered a lot of ground on Newtonian Mechanics”

Is the usage of idiom correct here? I have never seen its usage with the concept or a topic (i.e., on Newtonian Mechanics).

Also, are there other idioms which could be used in the same vein?

Answer (score 4):

I've always known this expression to have both a literal and figurative meaning, and have seen it used in both scenarios. For example:

Lit: **"We covered a lot of ground on our hike today."** - meaning we physically travelled a large distance over the course of the day.

Fig: **"We covered a lot of ground in Science class this semester."** - meaning we dealt with a lot of information in Science class.

So I would say that yes, the usage of the expression as an idiom with respect to a topic is valid.